# How to configure Spring 4 WebSocket with sockjs using xml configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

Hi my current websocket configuration is.

```
    <websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
        <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/chat">
            <websocket:sockjs></websocket:sockjs>
        </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
        <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
    </websocket:message-broker>
```

and my url pattern configuration is

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

if i change to pattern to '/' then it works fine else
the give an error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/demoapp/chat/info 404 (Not Found)
```

what is wrong please suggest.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `*.html` pattern, you're only mapping those requests to the DispatcherServlet - all other requests (in this case, all SockJS/websocket/etc requests) are ignored and an HTTP 404 error is returned by the servlet container.

So yes, you should be using `"/"` as a mapping pattern otherwise it won't work.

It can be hard to start writing a websocket application - a lot of new concepts and things to pay attention to. But the programming model is actually quite close to Spring MVC.

Here are a few pointers to help you:

- Some "light reading" of [the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) (schemas are really helpful)
- Try the [official getting started guide on websocket](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)
- Take a look at well designed example applications such as a [portfolio app](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) or a [chat room app](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat)

Answer (score 0):

How about
add this code

```
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

on web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

I'm use like this code
It work and doesn't show Path error